# Best tool for Microsoft Azure diagnostics for .net logging

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, diagnostics, log4view

Previously in my .net application I used NLog to write log in UDP which I used to view by log4View, now I am developing a web api service which I'll deploy to azure app service, is there any interactive tool like log4View for the web api service that will be deploy in azure app service?

I need to filtering facility by namespaces (like log4View), error, debug level? What type of logging I have to implement in .net for azure support like .net tracing/Etw?

Comment: Application Insights collects metrics and logs from applications. Log Analytics on the other hand collects logs and perf counters from any system, including custom logs. You should probably use both, ie Log Analytics to monitor your infrastracture (IIS, database,etc) and App Insight for dev-centerd monitoring.

Comment: There are custom solutions that integrates with your application. Here is [one](http://trypour.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/). It has the possibility of integration with NLog as far as I know as well, so you will do ordinary NLog and it will be gathered on the server by Application Insights with possibility to filter, etc. + it has a lot more than that in terms of diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented Application Insights in my ASP.NET MVC (Sitecore) website. It works like a champ and it integrates easily. You can send your own telemetry, integrate it with Log4Net or Nlog, make own events and so on. It wil generate some charts and reports and you can also make your own. I suggest to take a look at [this website](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-overview/).

Application Insights has a free version where you can collect 5M data points. This is not that much for a live website but it's enough to do some tests.